# How would I find out when a JWT token expires in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I'd like to figure out **when** a JWT token created from my Web API expires in ASP.NET Core. If I create a JWT token, and specify when it is expired in the `new JwtSecurityToken` call, how would I read that?

I'd like to find out during an authorized API call how much time there is **before that token expires**, and use that time to do a process.

There doesn't seem to be anything online. Thanks.

Comment: in your jwt token there is a claim called exp which shows the expiration time, by fetching that property you can do your process

Comment: @Elyas Esna how would I do that through ASP.NET Core's Authentication APIs?

Comment: `httpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "exp").Value;`

Comment: `User.FindFirstValue("exp")` is shorter. You need access to the ClaimsPrincipal object of course, either through a controller's User property, or through HttpContext. That's an extension, you'll need `using System.Security.Claims;`.